# google map api v2 show blank screen in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

This is **my manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="us.datn_02">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <permission
        android:name="us.datn_02.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="us.datn_02.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCompatTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="api key here" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".home.Home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="us.datn_02.map.Map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**activity_map.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Map" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This it my code in **Map.class**:

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    // Initializing

    // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    map = fm.getMap();

    GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
}
```

I get api key with package name is: us.datn_02.

Map activity is child of Home activity.

Why i get blank creen in Map activity?

Somebody can help me please?

Comment: I just tried your code, and it worked for me.  Note that I had to add this permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: if you don't add this permission. it work? @Daniel Nugent

Comment: It crashed for me without the permission, so I'm not sure if it's the same issue you're having.  Try adding it and see if it helps though.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **"api key here"** with actual generated android-api key

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="api key here" />
```

Comment: did you gave sample package name which you are using?

Comment: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="us.datn_02">`
I used this package name. But activity i used map fragment is: us.datn_02.map.Map

Comment: ues while generating andoird-keu for google play did u uused this package? did u enabled google map v2 in google console?

Comment: I used: `*SHA1 key*;us.datn_02` in google console. and I enabled google map v2 in google console. But I don't know why it's not work.

Comment: did u generated this some where else? and compile on another machine now?

Comment: No. I run it in a real device.

Comment: what's your mean? @N5

Comment: generateinf sha1 from another system than on machine on which u are compileing ur code

Comment: No. @N5. i used only one machine.

Comment: why using SupportMapFragment? you can use just MapFragment?